# pandas groupby and convert to json of defined schema

Tags: python, json, pandas, group-by, to-json

I have below pandas df :

```
id  mobile
1   9998887776
2   8887776665
1   7776665554
2   6665554443
3   5554443332
```

I want to group by on id and expected results as below :

```
id   mobile
1    [{"9998887776": {"status": "verified"}},{"7776665554": {"status": "verified"}}]
2    [{"8887776665": {"status": "verified"}},{"6665554443": {"status": "verified"}}]
3    [{"5554443332": {"status": "verified"}}]
```

I know to_json method won't help here and I have to write UDF. But I am new to this and bit stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with custom format for lists of dictionaries:

```
f = lambda x: [{y: {"status": "verified"}} for y in x]
df = df.groupby('id')['mobile'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   id                                             mobile
0   1  [{9998887776: {'status': 'verified'}}, {777666...
1   2  [{8887776665: {'status': 'verified'}}, {666555...
2   3             [{5554443332: {'status': 'verified'}}]
```

If need `json` format:

```
import json

f = lambda x: json.dumps([{y: {"status": "verified"}} for y in x])
df = df.groupby('id')['mobile'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df)
   id                                             mobile
0   1  [{"9998887776": {"status": "verified"}}, {"777...
1   2  [{"8887776665": {"status": "verified"}}, {"666...
2   3           [{"5554443332": {"status": "verified"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks.. This is exactly what i was looking for.  Can you help me explain the f statement here ? I really need to learn this for any further situations.

Comment: @j' - It is lambda function, same like `df = df.groupby('id')['mobile'].apply(lambda x: [{y: {"status": "verified"}} for y in x]).reset_index()`, I choose this format for nicer output. Also is possible create non lambda function from `f` like `def f(x): return [{y: {"status": "verified"}} for y in x]`